How to hide a button with multiple forms in page?
I have an e-commerce page, in the page I have multiple forms each with a different name and id but every button has the same id and name., e.g;
<form method="post" name="form12345" id="form12345" action="..."> 
    <input type="button" class="btn-BuyOff" value="Acquista" id="addtocart" name="addtocart">
</form>

How can I modify the visibility of the button in a specific form using the instruction in Javascript:
document.getElementById('addtocart').style.visibility = 'hidden';

the code above modify only the first button in the page, I need to address a specific button in the page.
Note: I can not modify the id or name of the buttons because the original code is automatically generate by the e-commerce.
Example:


<form name="form1" id="form1">
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" id="addtocart">
</form>
<form name="form2" id="form2">
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" id="addtocart">
</form>
<form name="form3" id="form3">
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" id="addtocart"> // this is the button to hide
</form>
<form name="form4" id="form4">
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" id="addtocart">
</form>




You could use: document.querySelector('#form3 > input').style.visibility = 'hidden'  But the core problem here is that you're re-using the same id which makes the markup invalid.  Whatever approach you take, your first step would be to correct the markup.

document.querySelector(\[name=${form}] #addtocart`).hidden = true;`

@mplungjan  Document: forms property Wouldn't it be simpler?

@MisterJojo I distrust those properties - ever since we used if (document.images) to test if IE supported image hovering ;)

@mplungjan Fortunately, IE no longer exist and Microsoft has definitely stopped trying to hijack W3C standards...

element's name are hierarchical dependent in each form: (see Document: forms property )
so, ther is no real interest to use id attributes in a form.


const formName = 'form3';

document.forms[formName].addtocart.style.visibility = 'hidden';


// document.forms.form3.addtocart.style.visibility = 'hidden';
form {
 height     : 2em;
 background : lightgreen;
 margin     : 0.5em;
 }
<form name="form1" >
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" >
</form>
<form name="form2" >
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" >
</form>
<form name="form3" >
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" > // this is the button to hide
</form>
<form name="form4" >
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" >
</form>




Thanks @mister-jojo, your answer is close to be the solution!
The problem I have is that the form name has to be passed as parameter, sometime it is the form1, sometime the form4 and so on.
how can I pass the form# parameter in the instruction:
document.forms.form#.addtocart.style.visibility = 'hidden';
??

@AndreaPizzorni  this use JS object notation syntax, see my update

you solved the problem! thanks a lot!

@AndreaPizzorni You are welcome! Many interface issues are implemented directly in JavaScript. Most other languages ​​do this through dedicated libraries, and programmers are more used to ID referencing logic, without grasping the benefits of the unified approach in HTML/CSS/JS.

Here is an alternative using querySelector/querySelectorAll


let showForm = 'form3';
// Hide only form3's button
document.querySelector(`[name=${showForm}] #addtocart`).hidden = true;

// Hide all except 3 - I find all forms with name starting with form

document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click',() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('[name^=form]').forEach(form => form.addtocart.hidden = form.name !== showForm);
});
<form name="form1" id="form1">
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" id="addtocart" value="1">
</form>
<form name="form2" id="form2">
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" id="addtocart" value="2">
</form>
<form name="form3" id="form3">
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" id="addtocart" value="3"> // this is the button to hide
</form>
<form name="form4" id="form4">
    form content
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" id="addtocart" value="4">
</form>

<button type="button" id="show">Show only form 3</button>




I would be hesitant to use a duplicated ID in any selector. Even if it works at the moment, it would be perfectly reasonable for a new browser (or future updates to existing browsers) to stop searching for IDs after the first match. Something like a name attribute selector might be more reliable long term.

Sure. However you are allowed to use any attribute in querySelector but not a duplicate ID in document.getElementById. Also you can see I use the name in the loop
